# How to pass 2D array into a function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I made this code :

```
int n,m;

void print(int a[][m])
{
int i=0,j=0;
    for(;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
int a[100][100];
int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    print(a);

return 0;
}
```

But I cannot recollect the complete 2D array that I passed.

If my input is

```
4 4
1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
5 4 3 2
```

I get an output of

```
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

What can I do to pass complete array into the function?

Comment: `void print(int a[][m])` --> `void print(int a[][100])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may enter m of value 4, but the array a is still of size `100`. Thus when you write `scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);` for `i = 1`, you are reading the 101-th element of the array, which is not a part of the first 16 elements. You will need to have `a` of size `m` in order to do what you try to do.